# How to run node js application using supervisor without command promt(i.e I want run in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am new for node js application and started learning node js with express framework.I want application will restart if some changes occur in js files.I have tried using supervisor with command prompt.It working fine.

First I have installed supervisor globally using following command.

npm install supervisor -g

Then I run app.js(i.e application start file) using supervisor in command mode.
supervisor app.js

Then I have change js file and refresh application.The changes are made automatically without restarting.
But now i want run in eclipse?I dont know how to setup supervisor in eclipse and how to run application using supervisor in eclipse.

I am using eclipse juno release 2 .

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.nodeclipse.org/history

Since 0.17 Run with Node Monitor is hidden and TCF Terminals are recommended to launch supervisor, forever, nodemon ...etc